# Reason that Raspberry PI running under Mono 4.4.2 requires the MonoApplications line rather than the MonoApplicationsConfigDir line

Tags: pi-3, mono

For Raspberry PI 3, in order to make sure there is an one to one mapping between apache2 server processes and `mod_mono_server4` processes, the `/etc/mono_server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf` file must contain exactly the following lines:

```
# Default configuration, don't edit it!
<IfModule mod_mono.c>
  MonoUnixSocket default /tmp/.mod_mono_server4
  MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
  AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx
  MonoApplications /:/home/richard/DevelopmentX64/HVR-Web-App
  MonoPath default /usr/lib/mono/4.5:/usr/lib
</IfModule>
```

Please note that the MonoApplications line is required so that all the mod_mono_server4 process instance have identical argument lists.

However in Ubuntu 16.04 the aforementioned change is not necessary.

What is the reason that Raspberry PI running under Mono 4.4.2 requires the 
`MonoApplications` line rather than the `MonoApplicationsConfigDir` line?

Comment: You have not cited your sources.  If the bulk of the stuff you quote above is simply from someone's blog, they might have written exactly the same thing about Ubuntu -- but they didn't write anything about Ubuntu.  I.e., it could be just someone's preferred strategy, and nothing to do with the anything much about the Pi.

Comment: @goldilocks, My source is my side-by-side comparison of the /etc/mono_server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf file in Raspberry PI 3 and Ubuntu 16.04.Could the reason that Ubuntu 16.04 ignores the MonoApplicationsConfigDir line in /etc/mono_server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf file  be related to the contents of debian.webapp? Thanks.

Comment: I don't use mono so I don't have an answer for you, but if the "in order to make sure [...] file must contain exactly the following lines" are *your words* (or, are they from comments in that config file?  **It is not clear...**) then it still seems like an assumption, not a fact.  Half the config files on the system say "Do not edit!", sometimes it is because they are prone to being overwritten by system updates but most often it is just spurious and really means, "Do not edit unless you know what you are doing".

Comment: There are a variety of unusual choices made by the people who package Raspbian, some of which, TBH, seem silly to me (note they do not have anything like the manpower of Debian or Ubuntu).  So I don't see any reason to believe this is anything more than just a personal choice made by the packager.  But someone who uses mono may come along with a better explanation.  It could have to do with other choices made by the packager which do make it necessary.

Comment: @goldilocks, Thank you for your comments. I will ask the people who use mono about this topic.Please explain your comment , "It could have to do with other choices made by the packager which do make it necessary."

Comment: Again, I don't use mono so that's just a casual guess about possibilities *presuming* you are right about it being necessary.  My general point is  you need to explain further why you *think* the config file "must contain exactly the following lines".  Is there some documentation that actually says that?  Did you try the config from Ubuntu and it did not work?   Beyond the "Do not edit!" bit, do you have any reason to believe it or is it just an *assumption* because that's how it is done by default on Raspbian?

Comment: @goldilocks, Could I ask you to sanity check my conclusion that the Raspberry PI gets confused when it sees the apache2.conf / httpd.conf file's Mono settings conflict with the mono settings in mono-server4-hosts.conf. So, the argument lists must be identical among all mod-mono-server4 intstances to combat confusion.

Comment: I don't even use *apache* (or at least, as little as possible and not on the pi), much less mono, so no.  If you are saying *you* have checked this, then you should edit that into the question ("I tried it this way _____ but it did not work [or _____ happened instead]").  If you haven't tried it and you don't have any further reason to believe it is necessary, *you should test it* -- it is going to take you forever to get anything done if you have to ask people online to test everything for you rather than doing it yourself...

Comment: @goldlicks, You are absolutely correct that it has nothing to do with Raspberry PI 3 versus Ubuntu 16.04 difference. I will try to answer the question soon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Apache2 server gets confused when it sees that  the apache2.conf file's , also referred to as httpd.conf file,  Mono settings conflict with the mono settings in mono-server4-hosts.conf if debian.webapp is not completely configured. For example, a completey configured debian.webapp looks like this:

```
<apps>
  <web-application>
    <name>test</name>
    <vpath>/test</vpath>
    <path>/var/www/html</path>
  </web-application>
</apps>
```

So, the argument lists must be identical among all mod-mono-server4 intstances to combat confusion by the apache2 server.

Comment: @Moderator, I am honored to receive your 10 reputation points from half an hour ago. Thank you,